# Content-driven API or RSS feed

Tags: api

I'm looking for a few content-driven APIs and RSS feeds for a mashup website i'm building. Like Yahoo! News and Flickr, which allow you to submit a GET request and get a list of items based on a specific keyword. Like getting all news about "michael jackson" and pictures of "R2D2".

Do you guys know any other public APIs and RSS feeds with such feature, without rate limits?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can find [here](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=News) something; but what would be a business model of an API "news for free" provider?

Answer (score 1):

You can use search terms in [Google News's RSS feed](https://news.google.com/news/feeds?output=rss&q=stack%20exchange).

See [documentation](https://support.google.com/news/answer/59255?hl=en) for more details.

Comment: Just be aware that [the things you can legally do with Google's RSS feed](https://support.google.com/news/answer/40796) are rather limited, and that this is not quite open data.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here's a [collection of content APIs](https://github.com/GSA/.Gov-Content-as-an-API) from the US government.

*Disclaimer: I'm a Sr. API Strategist for GSA.*